# Static Method Call

Tags: oop, static, constructor, static-methods

I have one class which has one static method as shown below.

```
class A
{
  A()
  {
     Initialize();
  }

  static void fm()
  {
    ;
  }

  void Initialize()
  {
     ;
  }

}
```

Now in the program if i call A.fm(), Will it call the `Initialize` method or not?

Comment: it will not call the `Initialize` method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is in a language like C++, Java, or C#:

It will not.  Constructors only get called when `new` is used or when a variable of that type (A in this case) is declared as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for a static constructor, if so and if youre using c# you might wanna run this code. Static constructors grants that you run **initializing code** before running any other code within the class.

```
public class A
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("METHOD!!!");
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INSTANCE METHOD!");
    }

    static A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STATIC CTOR");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A.Method();
        new A().Method2();
        A.Method();
        A.Method();
        A.Method();
        A.Method();
        A.Method();
        A.Method();
    }
}
```

Its then the output!

```
STATIC CTOR
METHOD!!!
INSTANCE METHOD!
METHOD!!!
METHOD!!!
METHOD!!!
METHOD!!!
METHOD!!!
METHOD!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the Initialize will not be called as it is inside a default constructor. If you make your default constructor also static, then the Initialize method will be called first in sequence and after that the fm() method will be called..